# How to remove path after domain name from string

Tags: php, path

I have the following code :

```
function removeFilename($url)
{
    $file_info = pathinfo($url);
    return isset($file_info['extension'])
        ? str_replace($file_info['filename'] . "." . $file_info['extension'], "", $url)
        : $url;
}

$url1 = "http://website.com/folder/filename.php";
$url2 = "http://website.com/folder/";
$url3 = "http://website.com/";
echo removeFilename($url1); //outputs http://website.com/folder/
echo removeFilename($url2);//outputs http://website.com/folder/
echo removeFilename($url3);//outputs http:///
```

Now my problem is that when there is only only a domain without folders or filenames my function removes website.com too.

My idea is there is any way on php to tell my function to do the work only after third slash or any other solutions you think useful.

Comment: sadly I didn't got any good answer that I want .

Comment: all answers are good but not perfect

Comment: check my answer, now its fulfill all your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED :** ( working and tested )

```
<?php
function removeFilename($url)
{
        $parse_file = parse_url($url);
        $file_info = pathinfo($parse_file['path']);
        return isset($file_info['extension'])
            ?  str_replace($file_info['filename'] . "." . $file_info['extension'], "", $url)
            :  $url;        
}

$url1 = "http://website.com/folder/filename.com";
$url2 = "http://website.org/folder/";
$url3 = "http://website.com/";

echo removeFilename($url1); echo '<br/>';
echo removeFilename($url2); echo '<br/>';
echo removeFilename($url3);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
http://website.com/folder/
http://website.org/folder/
http://website.com/
```

Comment: if s  it windows com file ?

Comment: and if url is .org or .net?

Comment: @mus , its also working for all ( .org, .com, .net etc)

Comment: yes now it's a perfect answer ;) u updated it (y) because first u had $file_info['extension'] != 'com'

Comment: ok this is the accepted answer thanks for your help have a good day ! ♥

Comment: hehe I need 15 reputation ;)

Comment: once I get 15 reputation I won't forget you because your answer is beatiful , it was smart using parse_url to get only path from url and then check for extension

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are wanting to replace a substring and not the whole thing. This function might help you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

pathinfo cant recognize only domain and file name. But if without filename url is ended by slash

```
$a = array(
"http://website.com/folder/filename.php",
"http://website.com/folder/",
"http://website.com",
);

foreach ($a as $item) {
   $item = explode('/', $item);
   if (count($item) > 3)
      $item[count($item)-1] ='';;
   echo implode('/', $item) . "\n";

}
  result

http://website.com/folder/
http://website.com/folder/
http://website.com
```

Comment: your code tries to remove every last folder of the path

Comment: it can't remove filenames if the url is like this http://website.com/filename.php/

Comment: Yes. i've written this in begining of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since filename is at last slash you can use `substr` and `str_replace` to remove file name from path.

```
$PATH = "http://website.com/folder/filename.php";

$file = substr( strrchr( $PATH, "/" ), 1) ; 
echo $dir = str_replace( $file, '', $PATH ) ;
```

**OUTPUT**

> http://website.com/folder/

Comment: can you please explain why its not working???what output or error you get???also explain how you test this code???

Comment: No its give `http://website.com/` check the outpot of it `$PATH = "http://website.com/";

$file = substr( strrchr( $PATH, "/" ), 1) ; 
echo $dir = str_replace( $file, '', $PATH ) ;`

Comment: http://website.com / this will outputs http://website.com / but http://website.com this will outputs http://

Answer (score 0):

Close to the answer of splash58

```
function getPath($url) {
    $item = explode('/', $url);
    if (count($item) > 3) {
        if (strpos($item[count($item) - 1], ".") === false) {
            return $url;
        }
        $item[count($item)-1] ='';
        return implode('/', $item);
    }
    return $url;
}
```